# Summarizing columns using a vector with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I want to calculate the mean of certain columns (names stored in a vector), while grouping against a column. Here is a reproducible example:

```
Cities <- c("London","New_York")
df <- data.frame(Grade = c(rep("Bad",2),rep("Average",4),rep("Good",4)),
                 London = seq(1,10,1), 
                 New_York = seq(11,20,1), 
                 Shanghai = seq(21,30,1))

> df
     Grade London New_York Shanghai
1      Bad      1       11       21
2      Bad      2       12       22
3  Average      3       13       23
4  Average      4       14       24
5  Average      5       15       25
6  Average      6       16       26
7     Good      7       17       27
8     Good      8       18       28
9     Good      9       19       29
10    Good     10       20       30
```

The output I want:

```
> df %>% group_by(Grade) %>% summarise(London = mean(London), New_York = mean(New_York))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Grade   London New_York
  <fct>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Average    4.5     14.5
2 Bad        1.5     11.5
3 Good       8.5     18.5
```

I would like to select the elements within vector `cities` (without calling their names) inside `summarise`, all while retaining their original name within the vector

Comment: Note that you can simplify the code if you have a column for Cities which would make the analysis easier (you would only need to filter by the cities on your vector and then summarise.

Comment: Do you mean combine all the values into one column and then add another column for the city? So 3 columns in total?

Comment: Yes, you might need pivot_longer from tidyr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Grade) %>%
 summarise_at(vars(one_of(Cities)), mean)

  Grade   London New_York
  <fct>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Average    4.5     14.5
2 Bad        1.5     11.5
3 Good       8.5     18.5
```

From documentation:

> one_of(): Matches variable names in a character vector.

Comment: Perfect, just a follow up question on the need/use of vars(). Why does R fail to select the variables without this function?

Comment: Look at the documentation: "This helper is intended to provide equivalent semantics to select(). It is used for instance in scoped summarising and mutating verbs (mutate_at() and summarise_at()).".

Answer (score 0):

`vars` can take a `vector` of column names as such.  `select-helpers`(`matches`, `starts_with`, `ends_with` are used when we have some kind of pattern to match).  Now, with the current implementation `vars` is more generalized, it can select columns, deselect (with `-`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(Grade) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(Cities), mean)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Grade   London New_York
#  <fct>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 Average    4.5     14.5
#2 Bad        1.5     11.5
#3 Good       8.5     18.5
```